# Clicking on identical Image having same src as other images and no href in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have 3 rows in a table like structure ,where an image is present as edit button for all the 3 rows separately but identical. to edit that row, I need to click on that image but it have below properties: and this id(1526885146519) is dynamic.I need to click all edit buttons one by one. What should I do to click them?

```
<img src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png" 
     onclick="fnEditRow(1526885146519);" 
     style="cursor: pointer; margin-right: 3px; margin-left: 3px; wdith; width:18px; height:18px;" 
     title="Eidt Item">
```

Table-rows HTML Properties-

G450A1SK1200A00G450A1SK1200A00E-Active1668.70668.700.00Pending
                                FRSM15062411200FRSM15062411200E-ACTIVE13107.003107.000.00Pending
                                31021200L--31021200E-ACTIVE16.406.400.00Pending

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: It will have more properties than just ID. There is several options how to do it. Share the HTML source code of that page so someone can help you.

Comment: HTML propery<img src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png" onclick="fnEditRow(1526885146519);" style="cursor: pointer; margin-right: 3px; margin-left: 3px; wdith; width:18px; height:18px;" title="Eidt Item">

Comment: @DebanjanB - screenshot is not of error or code , it is of app to give idea how does it looks like.

Comment: @Samira,  seems the `catalogue number` is unique, you can find the row by it and then find the edit button inside the row.  If this solution is acceptable,  Please show HTML code of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `x-path` or `css-selector` to locate them.

The possible xpaths are,

```
//img[@src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png"]
//img[@src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png" and @title="Edit Item"]
//img[@title="Edit Item"]
//img[starts-with(@onclick,'fnEditRow')]
```

css selector

```
img[src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png"]
img[title="Edit Item"]
```

or if it is under table tag then, you can use the x-path like

`//table/tr/td[last()]/img`

you can use find elements of web driver to get all elements and loop it as given below.

I am using java here,

```
List<WebElement> lstElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@title=\"Edit Item\"]");
for(WebElement ele:lstElements){
   ele.click();
   //do other stuffs
}
```

or use Index to get the specific indexed elements like

```
(//img[@src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png"])[1] -- first edit button

(//img[@src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png"])[2] -- second edit button

(//img[@src="../../../Intranet/Images/if_edit_173002.png"])[3] -- third edit button
```

Comment: IF I take something like this.. //img[@title="Edit Item"] or //img[starts-with(@onclick,'fnEditRow')]   It will always take the 1st edit button. I want to click all 3 edit buttons one by one in the different rows.

Comment: use find Elements and loop it. or use index to get specific element